# Add second row of model data below Django select menu choice

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have all of my choices rendering in the dropdown menu but I was wondering if it was possible to add a second row of descriptive subtext below each choice that shows in the menu.

```py
    class FootballLineup(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = FootballContestEntry
            fields = ['qb']

        qb = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='',                               
                                    queryset=NFLPlayer.objects.filter(active=True, 
                                                                      position='QB'), 
                                    empty_label="Select Quarterback", 
                                    required=True)

        qb.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'text-center lineup-select marker'})
```